# Uncaught TypeError: in inspect tool

Tags: javascript

```
</head>
<body id-"idbd">
<p id="helloworld">Message will display here</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
Document.getElementById("idbd").style.backgroundcolor="red";
</script>
</body
```

This is my code when I open it in browser background color remains white and  this error is showing.

(Uncaught TypeError: Document.getElementById is not a function     at document.html:10) 
Help me what to change in my code for red background????

Comment: `document` not `Document`, notice the lowercase `d`

Comment: `Document` is the constructor (class), `document` is an instance of `Document`. `getElementById` is an instance method so you should use `document.getElementById`. Also it's `backgroundColor` not `backgroundcolor`

Answer (score 1):

A few things to change:

**1.**
The [document](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp) object needs to be lower-cased.

Change:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Document.getElementById("idbd").style.backgroundcolor="red";
</script>
```

To:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("idbd").style.backgroundcolor="red";
</script>
```

**2.** `=` is used to assign an attribute, not `-`.

Change:

```
id-"idbd"
```

to:

```
id="idbd"
```

**3.** Change `backgroundcolor` to `backgroundColor`, the `c` needs to be capitalized.

**4.**
You also need to make sure that you close all your tags, such as the `head` tag.

---

Putting everything together, you can see the background turning red here:
https://jsbin.com/muqifojaza/edit?html,js,output

Final code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body id="idbd">
<p id="helloworld">Message will display here</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("idbd").style.backgroundColor="red";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fair enough point it out to the OP but simple typographical errors like these should be closed, not answered.

Comment: @George I agree on principle, but there is really a lot wrong with OP's code. I think it's fair to cover all of that in an answer.

Comment: You have two `<body>` tags.